# XAML text and Binding in one Textblock

Tags: xaml, binding, win-universal-app, uwp

Is there a way to make a `Texblock` with a normal text and a `Binding` in the same `Text` Proberty?

It should look like this :

```
<TextBlock  Text="Text {Binding SomeBinding}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nope.**
You should use a `IValueConverter` at this point.
If you don't know how to use an `IValueConverter`, the [official tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter) by Microsoft will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer :)